# Android Emulator Doesn't Start with error main/hash.c:133: _mesa_HashLookup_unlocked: Assertion `key' failed

Tags: android, emulation

I'm running the Android emulator on Ubuntu 12.04.  This happened after an Ubuntu update changed my desktop look unexpectedly.  I have no idea what the problem is and any help is apprecited.
The error is:

```
emulator-arm: main/hash.c:133: _mesa_HashLookup_unlocked: Assertion `key' failed.
```

Comment: Leave that emulator - advance to Genymotion - It's awsome!

Comment: Ok I will try that, but actually turns out my problem has to do with the graphics card driver.  Not sure why that was deleted or whatever changed I'm not sure.  Anyhow, sounds like a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, I really recommand genymotion - It's 3 times faster than emulator, even faster than my Samsung Galaxy SII